# Associative array - How to display values

Tags: php, arrays

I have array which looks like this:

```
"$companies" => array (6)
0 => 44.0
1 => 1399.0
2 => 0.0
3 => 2.0
4 => 750.0
12 => 0.0
```

where first number represent company ID and second number represent SUM() of one column from the table.

I belieave you skilled guys meet with something like this milions times (not like me.)
What i need is to create a table where each line is 1 company and in each line there are 2  where first gonna be ID and second gonna be value

```
                    <tr n:foreach="$companies as $company">                         
                        <td>{$company}</td>
                        <td class="center">{$company[1]}</td>                                                           
                    </tr>
```

Problem is that, I never know how many companies there gonna be, and what ID they will have so i can't use something like `echo $companies[0];`

How you suggest to add this to table?

Comment: Looks more like an enumerated array to me, enumerated = with numbers as keys

Comment: Can be, sorry if I didn't specify it correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<tr n:foreach="$companies as $company_id => $sum">                         
    <td>{$company_id}</td>
    <td class="center">{$sum}</td>                                                           
</tr>
```

`$company_id` would hold the key
`$sum` would hold the value

Comment: Damm I should make it by my self! Thank you @Ali, it was even easier then i think :)
Going to mark it as correct when in 5 min (when i will be able to)